# 3 dimensional matrices and vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Let A be a $3 \times 3$ matrix such that
$A\begin{pmatrix}3\\4\\5\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 7 \\ -13 \end{pmatrix}, A \begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 5 \\ 6 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -6 \\ 0 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix}, A \begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ -9 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 3 \\ -11 \end{pmatrix}.$

Find $A\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ -11 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}.$

So, bashing gives me a lot of equations. My dad tells me to find out how $\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ -11 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$ compares to the other vectors. I don't quite understand. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** if we could find constants $a,b,c$ such that
$$
\pmatrix{3\\-11\\-1} = 
a \pmatrix{3\\4\\5} +
b \pmatrix{4\\5\\6} + 
c \pmatrix{5\\-9\\1}
$$
then we'd be able to say
$$
A\pmatrix{3\\-11\\-1} = 
a A\pmatrix{3\\4\\5} +
b A\pmatrix{4\\5\\6} + 
c A\pmatrix{5\\-9\\1}
$$
Finding such $a,b,c$ amounts to solving the system
$$
\pmatrix{
3&4&5\\
4&5&-9\\
5&6&1}
\pmatrix{a\\b\\c} = 
\pmatrix{3\\-11\\-1}
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** because multiplication by a matrix is a linear transformation, if you can make your fourth vector a linear combination of the other three vectors, the product $A\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 3 \\ -11 \end{pmatrix}.$ will be the same linear combination of the other $3$ product vectors.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can also find $A$

$$
       A=\left(
 \begin{matrix}
        a & b & c \\
        d & e & f \\
        g & h & i \\
        \end{matrix}\right)
$$

If you write the first equation with that, you see the pattern of the variables based on matrix multiplication

$$
\begin{align}
      3a +4b +5c &= 2\\
      3d +4e +5f &= 7\\
      3g +4h +5i &= -13\\
\end{align}
$$

If you now shove all the unknowns into a vector and the rest in a matrix, you can (hopefully) invert that matrix to find the unknowns.

$$
\left(\begin{matrix}
      3 & 4  & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
      0 & 0 & 0 & 3  & 4  & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
      0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3  & 4  & 5 \\
      4 & 5  & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 0 & 0\\
      0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 5  & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
      0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
      5 & -9  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
      0 & 0 & 0 & 5 & -9  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 & -9 & 1\\
\end{matrix}\right)
\left(
\begin{matrix}
a\\
b\\
c\\
d\\
e\\
f\\
g\\
h\\
i\\
\end{matrix}
\right)
=
\left(\begin{matrix}
2\\
7\\
-13\\
-6\\
0\\
4\\
3\\
3\\
-11\\
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

Knowing the elements of A, you can multiply A by that vector.